File select disables valid documents
I have a simple webpage where a user can upload an excel document. I only want to accept xlsx files. To do this I simply added the extension to the input element as follows:
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="templateFileInput" accept=".xlsx" />

This works as expected. However I'm noticing an issue that might be Mac or Chrome related. If I open said document, edit, save, then close the document. When I go to select the file it is greyed out. In order to select the document I must select another folder then go back to the location where the file is and it appears enabled again. Am I doing something incorrectly or is this a bug with Chrome that I won't be able to fix?
